# UIActivityViewController Facebook and Twitter share not working in released iOS version

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

We have recently released iPhone app which share to fb & tw using UIActivityViewController like as zigzag app on app store.

My device is working perfect as my device is used for development.
But all users who downloaded this app not able to share using this function.

```
NSString *txtToShare = @"Please try this awesome iOS app";
NSArray *objectsToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:txtToShare, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{

}];
if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)])
{
    // iOS 8+
    UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [activityVC popoverPresentationController];

    presentationController.sourceView = sender; // if button or change to self.view.
}
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What does "not able to share" mean?  Nothing comes up when a button is pressed?  There are no options for sharing mediums?  etc.  Also provide the code that controls all of this.

Comment: This is an issue with iOS 8.3. A bug report has been submitted.

Comment: When i try to share share text and image  on Facebook on iOS version 8.2, only image is getting shared without text and with twitter it shows connection failed error. @DanielStorm do you have any information regarding this, will be helpful for me. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I resolved this using following technique
Declared two constants

```
static NSString *const twitterAppBundleStringForOS8 = @"com.atebits.Tweetie2.ShareExtension";
static NSString *const facebookAppBundleStringForOS8 = @"com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension";

if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] || [self.activityType isEqualToString:facebookAppBundleStringForOS8]) {
        text = @"abc";
    }
    else if( [self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] || [self.activityType isEqualToString:twitterAppBundleStringForOS8]){
        text = @"cc";
    }
```

It is working fine now

When I had issue I had following code

```
if ([self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ) {
            text = @"abc";
        }
        else if( [self.activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] ){
            text = @"cc";
        }
```

I hope it helps, if not then let me know.